# Sharing Class Variables

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

Here's a very short example of what i mean.

```
class class1():
    def method1(self):
        self.variable1 = 5
class class2():
    def method2(self):
        self.variable2 = var1.variable1 * 2
class class3():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = class1()
        self.var2 = class2()

instance = class3()
instance.var1.variable1 = 10
instance.var2.method2()
print instance.var2.variable2
```

the above code will obviously stop at the second-last line because class2 doesn't know what var1 is.

Now i know something like this is doable with subclasses, or just by keeping the methods all under the same class. But in my case i don't think (i'm not saying i know since i'm not very experienced, but i don't think) that it's a feasible solution.

Here's a [bigger sample code](http://pastebin.com/nVZtkeh4) (what i'm actually working with) and this isn't all of it, there are 2 other (even bigger) systems than this i need to implement (skills & perks). So if i'd be relying on subclasses i'd have one massive class loaded with sub-classes instead of many classes combined later-on in the code.

What are good ways to go about this? Am i just doing it all wrong?

Edit/Update: Another note, this code will be re-used multiple times for a lot of different variables, not just one (of course.)

Comment: There are a number of ways to resolve this. The one I find most obvious is to not have `class2` handle `method2`; move the logic somewhere that does know about the necessary objects, like `class3`.

Comment: @user2357112 like i said, i "think" that is not feasible, but now that you mention it, "chaining" it could possibly work, although it would complicate the code even further. (for example declaring a variable that uses class1 in class2 and then using class2 and class3 in class4, and so on instead of trying to merge class 1, 2 and 3 in class 4 like i am doing now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
class NotEnoughMagic(Exception):
    pass


class Character(object):
    fire = 0
    magic = 0
    hp = 100
    armor = 1
    def take_damage(self, amount):
        self.hp -= amount
        if self.hp <= 0:
            print '%s HAS DIED!' % type(self).__name__
    def walk(self):
        pass
    def attack(self, target, attack_points):
        target.take_damage(attack_points / target.armor)


class Monster(Character):
    fire = 50
    hp = 150
    armor = 2
    def punch(self, target):
        self.attack(target, 25)


class Magician(Character):
    magic = 10
    def magic_armor(self):
        self.hp += 20
        self.magic -= 10
    def sword_attack(self, target):
        self.attack(target, 20)
    def magic_attack(self, target):
        """Does tons of damage but uses all magic"""
        if self.magic > 0:
            self.attack(target, 100)
            self.magic = 0
        else:
            raise NotEnoughMagic()
```

Usage:

```
>>> monster     = Monster()
>>> magician = Magician()
>>> 
>>> print magician.hp
100
>>> print monster.hp
150
>>> 
>>> monster.punch(magician)
>>> magician.sword_attack(monster)
>>> 
>>> print magician.hp
75
>>> print monster.hp
140
>>> 
>>> monster.punch(magician)
>>> magician.magic_attack(monster)
>>> 
>>> print magician.hp
50
>>> print monster.hp
90
>>> 
>>> monster.punch(magician)
>>> magician.magic_attack(monster)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in magic_attack
__main__.NotEnoughMagic
>>> 
>>> print magician.hp
25
>>> print monster.hp
90
>>> 
>>> monster.punch(magician)
Magician HAS DIED!
>>> magician.sword_attack(monster)
>>> 
>>> print magician.hp
0
>>> print monster.hp
80
```

Some potential game logic:

```
>>> # Gang of monsters
... monsters = [Monster() for x in range(10)]
>>> magician = Magician()
>>> 
>>> # Prepare for battle
... while magician.magic > 0:
...     magician.magic_armor()
...     
... # Put on some chain mail
... magician.armor += 5
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    magician.armor += 5
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
>>> 
>>> while magician.hp > 0:
...     for m in monsters:
...             m.punch(magician)
... 
Magician HAS DIED!
Magician HAS DIED!
Magician HAS DIED!
Magician HAS DIED!
Magician HAS DIED!
Magician HAS DIED!
Magician HAS DIED!
>>>
```

---

Update:

Also, one thing to note are [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). For example, if you wanted to add additional functionality to a broad set of classes, but not down the entire inheritance tree.

```
class TeleportAbilityMixin(object):
    def teleport(self, destination):
        cost = 20
        if self.mp >= cost:
            # Unpack the x, y coordinates
            self.x, self.y = destination
            self.mp -= cost

class TeleportingMagician(Magician, TeleportAbilityMixin):
    pass

m = TeleportingMagician()
new_location = (10, 5)
m.teleport(new_location)
```

Comment: Although it doesn't directly answer my question i think... This is still very useful, and i learned a lot from it. Thanks!

In a way however i do think your "target" system does answer my question mostly, so i'll accept it as an answer :)

Comment: Oh nevermind, what really answered it was how you created the "Character" class and then continued in branches with "Monster(Character)" and "Magician(Character)" classes, that was how i chose to proceed with my code anyways. Took some minor modifications but i think it looks much better now. Thanks again!

Comment: I saw your code had a different sort of approach from typical object oriented approaches, so I wanted to show how one might do it in that fashion. Also, keep in mind, you could also subclass `Magician` or `Monster` in the same way you subclassed `Character`. For example: `class Dragon(Monster)` and then `class Whelp(Dragon): ...` and refine further and further down from the top.

Comment: Also, just for some extra help, I added a mixin example

Comment: I've rewritten some chunks of my original code to use the inheritance system you showed me. Inheritance is perfect for what i'm doing (although i occasionally use composition).

Mixins are also completely new to me, thanks a lot for pointing that out, it will no doubt prove useful soon. You've helped me a lot ^_^.